# Why do I have two partitions labelled D: in Disk Management, but only one D: in My Computer?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I tried to install "Remix OS" but failed. Then I figured out some problem of my hard disk.

In the first image- My Computer has 4 drive, but in the disk management it shows 5 drive, two drive with same letter D.

[image]

in the 2nd image- Partition 4 = Drive D+E+F.

[image]

why all of this messed up? can anyone have any explanation?

Comment: On Dynamic Disks, volumes can have multiple extents. So that's normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your disk is a [Dynamic Disk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_disks). This is a proprietary partition schema on top of MBR, created by Microsoft. It’s a [logical volume manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management), similar in many ways to [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) on Linux.

What you see in Disk Management are logical volumes that are physically stored in “Dynamic data” partitions.

A logical volume can have multiple extents (like your D: volume), even on multiple physical disks.

How you ended up having multiple “Dynamic data” partitions on a single disk, I don’t know. Perhaps a side-effect of converting the OS disk to Dynamic. Point is: `diskpart list partition` doesn’t “work” on Dynamic Disks, it just shows the backing MBR partitions, not the logical volumes.

To manage logical volumes, use `diskpart list|create|extend|delete volume`.

The disk being a Dynamic Disk is also the reason why Remix OS won’t work.

Unfortunately, your disk cannot be converted back to MBR with the multi-extent partition, even using third-party tools. It would be better to just backup the data and wipe the entire disk.

Comment: You beat me to it sir :-) I was 3/4 done preparing the same answer when you posted yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the last thing you said, can you help me with some more information? If I wipe the entire disk, will I be able to install Remix OS? Will it be converted to MBR automatically?

Comment: If you truly “wipe” the disk, it won’t have any partition schema at all. Windows will create automatically create a MBR (BIOS-booted) or GPT (UEFI-booted) schema when you reinstall it. Because you apparently need at least five partitions, I recommend going for GPT/UEFI.